# Ignore outliers in geom_bar and geom_histogram in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have dataframe

```
DF <- data.frame(respondent = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)), choice = as.numeric(c(1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 1000)))
```

When I plot it, the "1000" value makes the plot difficult to interpret:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(choice, 1,  ymax=10))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_y_continuous (limits = quantile(DF$choice, c(0, 10)
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1),
        text = element_text(size=20))
```

How can I remove the outlier from the plot? Is there a ggplot equivalent of `ylim` that I could simply set to "10"? There is a post on dealing with outliers in `geom_boxplot`, but I can't get the solutions to work in either `geom_bar` or `geom_histogram`.

Comment: I think you're looking for this to add to your construction: `+ ylim(0,10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `xlim` is what you're looking for?

```
ggplot(DF, aes(choice, 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  xlim(c(0, 11))
```

You'll get the warning `Warning message: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (position_stack).` indicating a data-point has been removed due to limits imposed.

I removed the other bits of code to make it a 'minimal example' - if it's important to your question then feel free to follow up.